# Unexpected behavior when nesting cd calls using Fabric

Tags: python, bash, fabric, cd

I am experiencing some troubles with Fabric (version 1.7.0 on Ubuntu 13.04).

Consider this function:

```
def does_not_work():
  with cd('/absolute/folder/one/'):
    with prefix('change_path_command'):
      with cd('/absolute/folder/two/'):
        run('some_random_command')
```

I expect it to execute the same command as:

```
def works():
  run('cd /absolute/folder/one/ && change_path_command && cd /absolute/folder/two/ && some_random_command')
```

However, here is the Fabric output of `fab does_not_work`:

```
Requested: some_random_command
Executed: /bin/bash -l -c "cd /absolute/folder/two/ && change_path_command && some_random_command"
```

It seems that nesting `cd`s is causing me troubles.

Is there a good explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`cd` context manager](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.7/api/core/context_managers.html#fabric.context_managers.cd) and the [`prefix` context manager](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.7/api/core/context_managers.html#fabric.context_managers.prefix) don't actually run commands when you invoke them, they just modify some local environment settings that affect any subsequent invocations of `run()` and/or `sudo()`.

So when your `run('some_random_command')` gets executed, it gets executed, it runs in the context of (`cd=/folder/one`, `prefix=change_path_command`, `cd=/folder/two`), and since the inner `cd` takes precedence over the outer `cd`, the end result is a single command executed with `cd /folder/two && change_path_command && some_random_command`.

Take a look at the source code for [`cd`](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/blob/master/fabric/context_managers.py#L246) and [`prefix`](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/blob/master/fabric/context_managers.py#L370) to a get a better idea of how that works -- all they ultimately do is modify the dictionary `fabric.state.env` when they enter and exit.  These later get applied in the call to [`_prefix_commands()`](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/blob/master/fabric/operations.py#L634), which gets called from `run()` and `sudo()` via the `_run_command()` function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! On [the doc](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.7/api/core/context_managers.html#fabric.context_managers.cd), they actually show how to nest `cd` commands but the first one is absolute and the second one is relative. How can I achieve what I am trying to achieve? FYI, the first absolute path is where a virtualenv is installed and the prefixing command is the `source bin/activate` to activate the virtualenv, the second absolute path is where the final command should be executed from.