# Using 2 cd() calls in the same Fabric execution

Tags: python, bash, virtualenv, fabric, cd

I recently [asked for explanations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18451553/unexpected-behavior-when-nesting-cd-calls-using-fabric) about a Fabric script behavior I couldn't understand. Now that I understand how Fabric works, I am still struggling to find a solution to my problem :-)

Basically, I wanted to nest a `cd()` call, a `prefix()` call (that would load some stuff from the current path) and another `cd()` call to finally `run()` a comment.

The best example that comes to my mind is the following:

```
with cd('/my/virtualenv/dir/'):
  with prefix('source bin/activate'):
    with cd('/my/project/dir/'):
      run('pip install -r requirements.txt')
      run('./run_something')
```

This would not work because `cd('/my/project/dir')` would take precedecence over `cd('/my/virtualenv/dir')`, which would be completely overridden from the context.

The only solution I can see is to concatenate the first 3 lines inside a unique `prefix()`, separated by `&&`s but it really seems hackish to me:

```
with prefix('cd /my/virtualenv/dir/ && source bin/activate && cd /my/project/dir/'):
  run('pip install -r requirements.txt')
  run('./run_something')
```

Is there another/more elegant way to do that? By "more elegant", I mean a solution that would use Fabric methods instead of my hack.

Of course, for this specific example, I could use virtualenvwrapper, but then it becomes too specific and does not work for other similar cases not based upon virtualenv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've gotten the following to work on my own machine:

```
with cd("~/somedir"), prefix("source ~/.virtualenvs/venv/bin/activate"):
    with cd("anotherdir"):
        run("ls")
```

The real question I have is, once you activate the virtualenv, why do you need to cd into another directory? This should work just fine for your purposes if you just want to install something using pip

```
with cd('/my/virtualenv/dir/'), prefix('source bin/activate'):
   run('pip install something')
```

I got the `with cd("dir"), prefix("stuff")` idea from the [fabric docs](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.6/api/core/context_managers.html) btw

**EDIT**:

As an update to my answer: Why not just use two absolute paths?

```
with cd("/abs/path/to/my/file"), prefix("source /abs/path/to/my/venv/bin/activate"):
    run("pip install something")
    run("./somefile.py")
```

Fabric will execute a command similar to what you were trying to input:

```
Executed: /bin/bash -l -c "cd /abs/path/to/my/file && source ~/abs/path/to/my/venv/bin/activate && pip install something"
```

Then it will run

```
./somefile.py
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Greg. I have edited my snippets to clarify the reason I need to `cd` in another directory. You are right, in this case it was useless but it comes from the fact that I simplified the context to avoid tons of useless lines in the snippets. Your first snippet works at the condition that the first `cd` is absolute **and** the second is relative. If they are both absolute, the first one is ignored, hence my problem.

Comment: Please let me know if it doesn't make it clearer or if you need more info. Since it is possible to nest `cd`s when path are relative, I still hope that a solution for absolute paths exist...

Comment: oh ok, I understand what your problem is. Lemme get the response back as soon as I test it out